# how to put french characters in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uilabel

I am fetching a json from server, json have some attributes where the value is in french. when I am assigning this french characters string to UILabel, it's giving me null.

How can I put this string in UILabel.

I am doing like this

```
cell.title.text =[dealDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.description.text =[dealDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
```

description and title both are in French.

Comment: its printing in console, i used NSLog to print the title and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that `cell.title` exists and that it is what you think it is? To persuade yourself that this should work, change your code like this:

```
cell.title.text = @"Même";
```

If that doesn't work, there's something wrong with `cell` or with `cell.title`.

If that works but your code doesn't, then perhaps there is something funny about what kind of object `[dealDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]` is. Try assigning it to an NSString and see what you get when you do.

In other words, you are making too many assumptions in a single line of code. Break down each assumption and test it. That is How To Debug.

Comment: cell.title.text = @"Même";

Its also not displaying.

Comment: Then try setting `cell.title.text` to `@"Hello"`. That won't work either. It has nothing to do with the French! Either `cell` is nil, or `cell` doesn't point to anything in the visible interface, or `cell.title` is nil, or `cell.title` doesn't point to anything in the visible interface. In other words, I'm just repeating what I said before: `cell.title` is not what you think it is.

Comment: It's fixed now ... Thanks, i have an internal mistake in flattening the html entities, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong property to set the text. Make sure you check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
cell.textLabel.text = [dealDictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dealDictionary objectForKey:@"description"];
```

For the detailTextLabel to be visible it needs to be a style that supports it.

***UITableViewCellStyleValue1***

> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with
>   left-aligned and black text; on the right side is a label that has
>   smaller blue text and is right-aligned. The Settings application uses
>   cells in this style.

***UITableViewCellStyleValue2***

> A style for a cell with a label on the left side of the cell with text
>   that is right-aligned and blue; on the right side of the cell is
>   another label with smaller text that is left-aligned and black. The
>   Phone/Contacts application uses cells in this style.

***UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle***

> A style for a cell with a left-aligned label across the top and a
>   left-aligned label below it in smaller gray text. The iPod application
>   uses cells in this style.

Comment: its my custom cell, i put these are the IBOutlets UILabel. Its showing  normal text, but not from those json string.